# Overpassing parent div

Tags: html, css, magento-go

I'm having problem with my magentoGo site.

I have 3 divs inside a content which need a 100% width but I am having a problem with the
other pages because the content is not centered. It needs to have a specific width so that the content will center on the page.

I tried position absolute of the 3 divs, give them width of 100%, left:0;, right:0; and a top which has a specific number so it is not overlapping to each other along with the footer

But after checking it the footer stick to the position where I placed in the home page and it not moving according to the content of the page.

Please help.

this is my site http://devozoo.gostorego.com/

Comment: Example speaks more than words. Show your code. create a fiddle.

Comment: Provide the code your using or create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). It will make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Here is my site http://devozoo.gostorego.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

as a style.